# How to prove this vector identity using triple product?

Tags: vector-analysis

Need to prove that

$$(\vec{v}\cdot\nabla)\vec{v}=\frac 12\nabla(\vec{v} \cdot \vec v) + (\nabla\times\vec v)\times \vec v$$

I could do it by applying the definitions directly, but triple product gives almost the right answer:

$$(\vec a\times \vec b)\times \vec c=-(\vec c\cdot\vec b)\vec a+(\vec c\cdot\vec a)b$$

In my case I get

$$(\vec{v}\cdot\nabla)\vec{v}=\nabla(\vec{v} \cdot \vec v) + (\nabla\times\vec v)\times \vec v$$

But $\frac 12$ is missing from the first member from the right side and I just can't see where that should  come from.

Comment: You can't just use vector identities as proofs of vector *operator* identities.  That is because vector operators (as in $\nabla$, $\nabla \cdot$, and $\nabla \times$) don't *behave* the same as vectors.  Sorry, but you're going to have to use the definitions directly here.  -- If you're finding that difficult, you might want to research index notation -- it usually makes proving these identities rather straightforward.

Comment: @Earthland I provided a straightforward way in my answer.  Let me know how I can improve the answer.  I just want to give you the best possible answer I can give you.  And an "up vote" and "best answer" vote are always much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using implied summation notation, the right-hand side maybe  written
$$\begin{align}
\frac12 \nabla(\vec v\cdot \vec v )+(\nabla \times \vec v)\times \vec v  & = \frac12 \hat x_i \partial_i (v_jv_j )-(\hat x_k v_k) \times \left((\hat x_l\partial_l) \times (\hat x_mv_m ) \right)\\
& = \frac12 \hat x_i \partial_i (v_jv_j )-[\hat x_k \times (\hat x_l \times \hat x_m )] v_k \partial_l (v_m )  \\
& = \frac12 \hat x_i \partial_i (v_jv_j )-[\delta_{km} \hat x_l-\delta_{kl} \hat x_m] v_k \partial_l (v_m )  \\
& = \frac12 \hat x_i \partial_i (v_jv_j )-[ \hat x_l v_k \partial_l (v_k )- \hat x_m v_k \partial_k (v_m )]  \\
& = \frac12 \hat x_i \partial_i (v_jv_j )-[ \frac12 \hat x_l  \partial_l (v_kv_k )-  v_k \partial_k (\hat x_mv_m )]  \\
& =  v_k \partial_k (\hat x_mv_m ) \\
& = (\vec v  \cdot \nabla)\vec v 
\end{align}$$

which proves the identity!